# How can I get my templates to work properly on my live site?

Tags: ee2, templates, multi-site-manager, url

I have a serious problem with my site.

I have recently made some changes to a site and its templates.

I uploaded all the correct items to the server via Beanstalk and git with a push to the remote repo.

When I login I am perfectly fine going into the templates but when trying to view pages the correct templates are not rendering properly at all. When I go to the templates in the editor they are correct but they are not showing up on the frontend at all. It uses the wrong template which is not the correct one for the url.

Has anyone got any ideas at all as to why this may happen?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify, is it that completely the wrong template is loaded or an out of date version of the template you have updated? Perhaps try synchronising the database and the files via Design > Templates > Synchronise Templates?

Comment: Hi, In the templates folder in the root directory they are out of date and then in the editor in the site template manager they all look fine to me. I am worried about synchronising the files and loosing everything though.

Comment: Backup your database first, then sync - it should always take the latest (which will be the database), but you could argue why hasn't it taken the latest version and auto-synced! Alternatively delete all the external file templates if you're that worried it will sync to the wrong template (DB vs File). Again always backup first!

Comment: That’s a reasonable concern, so do as Peter suggests and back up your database before you lose the copy you like. Funny thing is: aren’t the file versions the ones you just uploaded using Git? Are we certain the Git destination matches the configuration settings for saving files as templates? Please check that, too.